# Capturing all items in basket (R/arulesSequences)

Tags: r, sequences, arules

I am having an issue with the arulesSequences package in R. I was able to read baskets into the program, and create a data.frame, however it fails to recognize any other items beyond the first column. Below is a sample of my data set, which follows the form demonstrated here: [Data Mining Algorithms in R/Sequence Mining/SPADE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Sequence_Mining/SPADE).

```
    [sequenceID] [eventID] [SIZE] items
    2 1 1 OB/Gyn
    15 1 1 Internal_Medicine
    15 2 1 Internal_Medicine
    15 3 1 Internal_Medicine
    56 1 2 Internal_Medicine Neurology
    84 1 1 Oncology
    151 1 2 Hematology Hematology
    151 2 1 Hematology/Oncology
    151 3 1 Hematology/Oncology
    185 1 2 Gastroenterology Gastroenterology
```

The dataset was exported from SAS as a [.CSV] then converted to a tab-delimited [.TXT] file in Excel. Headers were removed for import into R, but I placed them in brackets above for clarity in this example. All spaces were replaced with an underscore ("_"), and item names were simplified as much as possible. Each item is listed in a separate column. The following command was used to import the file:

```
    baskets <- read_baskets(con = "...filepath/spade.txt", sep = "[ \t]+",info=c("sequenceID", "eventID", "SIZE"))
```

I am presented with no errors, so I continue with the following command:

```
    as(baskets, "data.frame")
```

Here, it returns the data.frame as requested, **however it fails to capture the items beyond the first column:**

```
    items sequenceID eventID SIZE
    {OB/Gyn} 2 1 1
    {Internal_Medicine} 15 1 1
    {Internal_Medicine} 15 2 1
    {Internal_Medicine} 15 3 1
    {Internal_Medicine} 56 1 2
    {Oncology} 84 1 1
    {Hematology} 151 1 2
    {Hematology/Oncology} 151 2 1
    {Hematology/Oncology} 151 3 1
    {Gastroenterology} 185 1 2
```

Line 5 should look like:

```
    {Internal_Medicine, Neurology} 56 1 2
```

I have tried importing the file directly as a [.CSV], but the data.frame results in a similar format to my above attempt using tabs, except it places a comma in front of the first item:

```
    {,Internal_Medicine} 56 1 2
```

Any troubleshooting suggestions would be greatly appreciated. It seems like this package is picky when it comes to formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Line 5 should look like:
>
> ```
> {Internal_Medicine, Neurology} 56 1 2
> ```

Check out

```
library(arulesSequences)
packageVersion("arulesSequences")
# [1] ‘0.2.16’
packageVersion("arules")
# [1] ‘1.5.0’
txt <- readLines(n=10)
2 1 1 OB/Gyn
15 1 1 Internal_Medicine
15 2 1 Internal_Medicine
15 3 1 Internal_Medicine
56 1 2 Internal_Medicine Neurology
84 1 1 Oncology
151 1 2 Hematology Hematology
151 2 1 Hematology/Oncology
151 3 1 Hematology/Oncology
185 1 2 Gastroenterology Gastroenterology
writeLines(txt, tf<-tempfile())
baskets <- read_baskets(con = tf, sep = "[ \t]+",info=c("sequenceID", "eventID", "SIZE"))
as(baskets, "data.frame")
#                            items sequenceID eventID SIZE
# 1                       {OB/Gyn}          2       1    1
# 2            {Internal_Medicine}         15       1    1
# 3            {Internal_Medicine}         15       2    1
# 4            {Internal_Medicine}         15       3    1
# 5  {Internal_Medicine,Neurology}         56       1    2 # <----------
# 6                     {Oncology}         84       1    1
# 7                   {Hematology}        151       1    2
# 8          {Hematology/Oncology}        151       2    1
# 9          {Hematology/Oncology}        151       3    1
# 10            {Gastroenterology}        185       1    2
```

Comment: this method doesn't seem to work for me. If i import the [.CSV] file, then use your first line of code `writeLines(file, file_tf <-tempfile())` i receive an error

Comment: @diaferiaj Why do you import it and then export it again using writeLines?

Comment: Isn't that what you're doing with the readLines command, followed by writeLines? Otherwise your code looks exactly like mine. It seems like the package is stopping at the first item in my case, or not recognizing that the SIZE variable should dictate how many columns to grab

Comment: @diaferiaj readLines + writeLines just recreates your CSV. Yes, the code is like yours. I deliberately added the package versions for you to compare. Other than that: perhaps the missing header line in the csv (mine hasn't got any)? Perhaps your csv uses different delimiters which you did not consider? Impossible to solve without having your data and session info.

Comment: I understand, and thought it might be difficult to identify the issue. arules is the same version, and arulesSequences is '0.2.17.' Both my csv and txt versions have no headers and they're supposed to be comma separated and tab delimited, respectively. I appreciate your consideration. I'll have to keep playing around with the settings and formats.

Comment: It seems like the error was born out of the item formatting. I created a key that translated each item to an abbreviation, and re-ran the code. The results mimicked the link that I posted: `{IM, NEURO} 56 1 2`